# Android camera:How to capture an image automatically by specified time

Tags: android, camera

How to capture an image automatically by specified time when camera is open.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it possible to capture image without user interaction. But for sure you can fire intent on specified time for showing the camera

you just need a timer and then if the time is equal to the time you wanted than

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), TAKE_PICTURE);
```

I think that is not possible to just take photo without user interaction cause it would be a security issue. Maybe for the things like camera is not that bad, but it is definitively bad if  you can programmatically make a call or send sms... For things like this you have user interaction to confirm. All you can do is fire a intent